# Custom Post Type Taxonomy remove category slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type 'Shop' with a custom taxonomy for Shop Categories

For my shop category archive pages I want the URL structure to be:

**example.com/shop/tech/** (instead of example.com/shop/category/tech/)

And I want Shop posts to be **example.com/shop/shop-post-title-example**

I have tried the code below and saved permalinks but when I visit a Shop post it shows a 404 error.

Is it possible to remove the category base without errors?

```
// Custom Post Type : Shop  
function my_custom_post_shop() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Shop', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Product', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Product' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Product' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Products' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Product' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No projects found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No projects found in the Trash' ), 
    'menu_name'          => 'Shop'
  );
  $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Shop' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'shop' ),
        'has_archive' => 'shop',
  );
  register_post_type( 'shop', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_shop' );

// Shop Categories
function my_taxonomies_shop() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Shop Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Shop Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Shop Categories' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'shop'),
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'shop_category', 'shop', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_shop', 0 );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the category base in custom taxonomy URLs with:

```
$args = array(

    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false),

    /* ...(other args)... */
);
register_taxonomy( 'shop_category', 'shop', $args );
```

And re-save Permalinks settings.

However, **this will make your (basic post type) posts go 404, if you have permalinks set to `Post name`**. It seems you cannot have both custom taxonomy and posts reside in the root. Therefore you would go to Permalinks settings and set `Custom structure` , e.g. `/blog/%postname%/`.

A side effect is that your CPTs would have this "front", too, e.g. `blog/yourcustomtype`. You can get rid of this with `'with_front' => false` in your product type registration:

```
register_post_type( 'yourcustomtype',  array(
           'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'yourcustomurl',
                'with_front' => false
            ),
            /* ... */
));
```

Found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/306620/89973).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in order to display custom post type and/or its category page, you would need to create template files (corresponding PHP files) first. Template files would pull your posts and display them.

For example, to display your categories "shop_category" you could create a file called "taxonomy-shop_category.php".
If you like to create a template specifically for "tech" Shop Category, then you can create a file called "taxonomy-shop_category_tech.php".
There is a hierarchy of templates: https://wphierarchy.com/
Also more about templates: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/
Nice article about custom post types taxonomies: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/taxonomy-archives-list-posts-by-post-type--cms-20340

Template files should be placed in your WordPress theme folder (or child theme folder)
!important. Don't forget to update your permalinks. Go to /wp-admin/options-permalink.php and click "Save Changes".

Here is an example of a simple template file:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }
?>
 
<?php get_header(); 
$term = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop',
    'shop-category' => $term->slug
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
 <header class="archive-header">
    <h1 class="archive-title">
        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
    </h1>
</header>
        <div id="content">
                 <?php
                 if ($query->have_posts()) {
                         
                    echo'<h2>Your shop category name ' . $term->name . '</h2>';
                     
                    echo '<ul>';
                     
                        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                 
                        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </li>
                         
                        <?php endwhile;
                         
                        echo '</ul>';
                         
                } 
                     
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>             
             
        </div><!-- #content -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not asking about template files, I'm asking about removing the category base in custom taxonomy URLs